# Probability Problem with numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are $n$ tickets on the table. Each ticket has a number written on it. The $i$-th ticket can be numbered $A_i$ with probability $P_i$ percent and with probability $100-P_i$ percent it can be numbered $B_i$. It can not have any other number(other than $A_i$ and $B_i$). A numbering of tickets on the table is correct if and only if all tickets have distinct ticket numbers.
So I have to find the probability that the numbering will be correct.

Given $P_i, A_i$ and $B_i$

Suppose there are $3$ tickets, and $P_i, A_i, B_i$ are as follows:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
100 & 1 & 3\\
47 & 2 & 1\\
74 & 3 & 2\\
\end{array}
$$
So what I am thinking is

for $1$. ticket number $1$ has $100\%$ probability so numbering will be $1$.

for $2$. ticket number $2$ has $47\%$ and ticket number $1$ has $53\%$ probability so number will be $1$.

for $3$. ticket number $3$ has $74\%$ and ticket number $2$ has $26\%$ probability so number will be $3$.

now with these probabilities, I am getting $1,1,3$ numbers of the tickets.

here my sample space is $3$ (n).

how to get the event, here $2$ tickets are numbered correctly and only $1$ ticket is distinct.

so I am confused how to get this, and Am I thinking correctly.

Correct Answer for the case is: $0.3478000$

Comment: Just because one number has a higher probability, doesn't make it certain. So your space of possible outcomes is bigger.

Comment: @Macavity Hmmmm Thank you for the reply.. how will I find the possible outcomes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the first ticket is guaranteed (with probability $1$) to be numbered $A_1 = 1$, the only way for our three tickets to have distinct ticket numbers is if the second ticket is numbered $A_2 = 2$ (since $A_1 = 1$, it can't be $B_2 = 1$) and the third ticket is numbered $A_3 = 3$ (since $A_2 = 2$, it can't be $B_3 = 2$). Hence, since we want the $i^{th}$ ticket to be numbered with $A_i$, we simply multiply together each of their corresponding probabilities $P_i$:
$$
P(\text{all distinct}) = P_1 \cdot P_2 \cdot P_3 = 1 \cdot 0.47 \cdot 0.74 = 0.3478
$$

Comment: Hmm thank you for the reply,what happens if this case:- n=2 and 50 1 2 and 50 2 1..

Comment: Do it by cases. Case 1: Suppose $A_1 = 1$. Then since we want the ticket numberings to be distinct, this forces the other ticket(s) to be either $A$ or $B$, and so on. Then do the same thing going the other direction (Case 2: Suppose $A_1 = 2$. Then...)

Comment: If A1=1 then for numbering of tickets to be distinct A2=2 or If A1=2 then for numbering to be distinct A2=1, so there are two events, probability = (0.50 * 0.50) + (0.50 * 0.50) = 0.50.
Am I correct sir ?

Comment: Yes, perfect. Good job.

Comment: Thank you sir, I got this :) and Sorry I dont have enough reputation to vote you up..

Comment: 1 more thing sir, suppose this is the case.. n=4 and 70 1 2, 74 3 1, 52 2 4, 47 3 2, Possible outcomes = (1,3,4,2) and (2,1,4,3), so my doubt is for large n, how will I find possible outcome..?
suppose n<=50 and Ai and Bi<=16